Losing CRS when writing to GPKG with OGR2OG / GDAL
CRS is getting set as undefined, no matter what I run. Not a biggy, but throws a warning when I import to QGIS.
Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug?
My codes:
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" -nlt POINT -a_srs EPSG:20355 'C:\Test.gpkg' "MSSQL:DSN=dsn;database=DBASE;tables=UV_FI;driver={SQL Server}"

ogrinfo 'C:\Test.gpkg' gpkg_contents -sql
"SELECT * FROM gpkg_contents"
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  table_name (String) = UV_FI
  data_type (String) = features
  identifier (String) = UV_FI
  description (String) =
  last_change (DateTime) = 2024/11/16 20:56:31.966+00
  min_x (Real) = 604072
  min_y (Real) = 7569720
  max_x (Real) = 611630
  max_y (Real) = 7584990
  srs_id (Integer64) = 99999

Possible related to https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/9580

I tried reproducing this using a shapefile without .prj file, but the srs was properly added to the GPKG... so possibly it is somehow specific to the MSSQL datasource...
